# A couple of questions in regards to this passage

Tags: meaning

I'm sorry for such an unclear title, but I really can't figure out a better one to include all my questions.

The following passage is quoted from "An Illustrated Brief History of Western Philosophy":

> One is sometimes invited to believe that the final stage in the understanding of Aristotle's metaphysics is an appreciation of the profound and mysterious nature of Being qua Being. **Rather**, the first step towards **such an understanding** is **the realization** that Being qua Being is a **chimerical spectre** engendered by inattention to Aristotle's logic.

1. What does ***rather*** at the beginning of second sentence mean here?
2. What does ***such an understanding*** in second sentence mean, does it mean "that the final stage in the understanding of Aristotle's metaphysics is an appreciation of the profound and mysterious nature of Being qua Being"?
3. What was engendered by inattention to Aristotle's logic, the realization or a ***chimerical spectre***? If the answer is latter.Then, what if I want to say the realization was engendered by inattention to Aristotle's logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‘Rather’ means ‘instead’.

‘Such an understanding’ refers to ‘the understanding of Aristotle's metaphysics’ as described in the previous sentence.

What has been engendered by ‘inattention to Aristotle's logic’ is the belief, false in the writer’s view, that ‘Being qua Being’ is something that deserves to be taken seriously. In reality, it is ‘a chimerical spectre’.

Comment: it's very clear, thanks! but I still have one question. What if I want to say that it is the realization which was engendered by inattention to Aristotle's logic,just curious, what is the right way to make that expression?

Comment: Well, I suppose you could say something like ‘Rather, the first step towards such an understanding is knowing that inattention to Aristotle's logic is itself the cause of the realization that Being qua Being is a chimerical spectre.’ But it wouldn’t make much sense.